# Probability of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each of which is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$.

Find the probability that $(X−\frac 1 2)^2+(Y−\frac 1 2)^2\leq \frac 1 9$. Give at least 8 correct digits after the decimal point. Hint: don't compute any integrals; think about this problem geometrically.

I understand that the uniform distribution means each value has an equal chance of occurring but it threw me off when saying don't compute any integrals.

Comment: Make a picture. A square and within it a disk.

Comment: Ahhh - the good old homework factory back at work. Same question from same class posted here yesterday:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95688/uniform-distribution-probability/   ... There really should be a time delay on answering these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$, i.e.
$$
P((X,Y)\in A)=\frac{|A|}{|[0,1]^2|}=|A|,\quad A\subseteq [0,1]^2.
$$
Now, express the probability that $(X-\tfrac12)^2+(Y-\tfrac12)^2\leq \tfrac19$ as $P((X,Y)\in A)$ for a suitable $A\subseteq [0,1]^2$ and compute.

Comment: i'm sorry I'm a little confused still

Comment: Confused by what?

Comment: How to express the expression as P(X,y) for a suitable A

Comment: Stefan means, draw a graph of $(x-\frac 12)^2 + (y-\frac 12)^2 = \frac 19$ and find out how it cuts the square $[0..1]^2$.  |A| is an expression of area.

Comment: @GrahamKemp $x-\frac{1}{2}$ must replace $x+\frac{1}{2}$ here.